# How to draw a grob on top of ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob, eulerr

I have a `grob` object (in my case it's `euler` plot) and a `ggplot` object, and I want to place one on top of another, for example:

```
library(eulerr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(a=sample(100),b=sample(50:149), c=sample(20:119))
venn <- euler(list(
  A=df$a,
  B=df$b[1:50],
  C=df$c
), shape='ellipse')

p_v <- plot(venn, quantities = T, fills=c('red','green','blue'))
p_g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()

# Now I want somehow to draw p_v on top of p_g
p_g + p_v
```

Should produce something like this:
[image: overlayed plot]

I tried using `ggplotify` for example but couldn't find a way to get rid of white rectangle that was drawn as a canvas for the second plot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `annotation_custom`:

```r
p_g + annotation_custom(p_v, xmin  = 0, xmax = 50, ymin = 80, ymax = 150)
```

[image]

If you want this to work with log axis scales, you will need to use `grid` to directly draw `p_v` over `p_g`. You will first need to put it in a grobtree so that you can specify its position and dimensions:

```r
p_g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10()

p_g 
grid::grid.draw(
  grid::grobTree(p_v$children,
                 vp = grid::viewport(x = unit(0.3, "npc"), 
                                     y = unit(0.7, "npc"), 
                                     width = unit(0.4, "npc"), 
                                     height = unit(0.5, "npc"))))
```

[image]

If you want this as a single R object, you can do:

```r
obj <- grid::grobTree(ggplotGrob(p_g), grid::grobTree(p_v$children,
                 vp = grid::viewport(x = unit(0.3, "npc"), 
                                     y = unit(0.7, "npc"), 
                                     width = unit(0.4, "npc"), 
                                     height = unit(0.5, "npc"))))
```

So that `obj` is now a `grob` of your whole picture.

One further way to do this would be using `geom_grob` from package `ggpmisc`:

```r
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(df, aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_grob(aes(x = 12.5, y = 100, label = list(p_v$children$canvas.grob)),
            vp.width = 0.3, vp.height = 0.4) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm... I should have made my example more closer to my real case: in my `p_g`, I have `scale_y_log10()` - and then it doesn't work with grob :(

Comment: @VasilyA give me a moment and I'll sort that out for you...

Comment: sorry for bothering again - how can I save the resulting combined plot as an object? If I understand correctly, `grid::grid.draw()` plots to the active graphical device, right?

Comment: @VasilyA you can use `png("my_png.png")` or `jpeg("my_jpeg.jpg")` or `pdf("my_pdf.pdf")` or whatever. Then run your plot code, then `dev.off()` and the file will save. Just remember to set your dimensions correctly - the grob will distort if you don't get the aspect ratio right.

Comment: oh I actually meant "saving" to an R object, in case if I want to add one more layer or do some other manipulations, and be flexible about printing it later. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: @VasilyA see my update. You can merge the ggplot and the Venn into a single grob object. Note that you won't be able to use ggplot syntax on this because ggplot has already rendered it. A more flexible alternative would be to store the ggplot and the Venn in a list.  If this is the kind of thing you will be doing a lot you might even consider making that structure an S3 class with its own plot method that renders the ggplot and Venn together.

Comment: @VasilyA I have added another solution using `geom_grob` that might work better for you

Comment: yes, that one is even better! Thanks again for all your help, I learned a lot from your answers!